# JQuery гармошка

Tags: jquery, javascript

Кликаешь на блок меняеться внизу текст. Но когда я хочу спрятать текст этого блока, тоесть нажать на этот же блок что бы спрятать текст, он не исчезает а подымается в верх и сново опускается. Как решить проблему?

**Пример** http://jsfiddle.net/ad8zr/23/

Это должно работать как гармошка, текст должен исчезать когда нажимаешь на любой другой блок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А если у вас будет 20 элементов в меню, вы для каждого будете писать отдельный код? Правильней было бы сделать вот так ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhukovroman/ad8zr/26/)):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".bottomsection").hide();
    $(".bloCkimg").show();
    // обрабатываем клики по меню с помощью одной функции
    $('.blockinthesidebar').click(function () {
        // найдем номер элемента, по которому кликнули
        var clickIndex = $('.blockinthesidebar').index(this);
        // найдем элемент для показа
        var elem = $('.bottomsection').eq(clickIndex);
        // ищем видимые, но не elem и скрываем их
        $('.bottomsection:visible').not(elem).slideUp();
        // тогглим elem 
        elem.slideToggle();
    });
});
```

Comment: опыт не позволяет мне писать такие функции, спасибо

Comment: @Zhukov Roman в `jQuery` вместо `inArray` другая функция более уместна: 

    $('.blockinthesidebar').index(this);

Comment: @lampa, абсолютно согласен, обновил ответ.

Comment: @zhukov-roman, как же я люблю вашу привычку использовать переменные там, где можно обойтись без них :)

Comment: @Crasher, вы считаете, что в данном примере много переменных? :) Можно подсократить на одну строчку, убрав `var clickIndex` - но зачем? Мне кажется, что так гораздо понятней для новичка в javascript-е.

Comment: [@Zhukov Roman](http://hashcode.ru/users/10590/zhukov-roman), простите, тут слегка придираюсь, просто подметил, что по коду узнаю автора :)

---

А по делу — по моему, отлично бы предоставлять и понятный вариант, и краткий, тоесть я бы дополнил ответ кодом:

    $(function(){
        $(".bottomsection").hide();
        $(".bloCkimg").show();
        $('.blockinthesidebar').click(function(){
            $('.bottomsection:visible').not($('.bottomsection').eq($('.blockinthesidebar').index(this)).slideToggle()).slideUp();
        });
    })

Хотя, это не обязательно, только пожелание.

Comment: @Crasher громоздко слишком.